# Configure cucumber in TeamCity to run unit tests only using tags (Maven)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, teamcity, cucumber-jvm, teamcity-9.0

I have both unit and acceptance tests in a maven project (spring boot). I would like to run unit tests only when my build runs in TeamCity. I am using cucumber.

When i run the tests via command line, everything works as expected (only unit tests are run)

```
 c:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn package -Dcucumber.options="--tags @unit"
```

However, in teamcity, all tests are being run (unit and acceptance). It seems teamcity ignores my cucumber.options

[image: TeamCity configuration]

In addition, when I double click on the 'test' lifecycle in Intellij, all tests are run as well (not just unit tests) So my guess is that TeamCity is doing exactly what the 'test' lifecycle does.

[image: intellij lifecycle]

**How can i get around this problem (in TeamCity)?**. I have tried using a 'Command line' step, which works, however, i lose all the tests reporting as well as test coverage reports.

[image]

i have solved the Intellij problem by creating (or changing) a configuration:

[image: intellij configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it this way in TeamCity:
`"-Dcucumber.options= --tags @unit"`